# Spark not working with pureconfig

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shapeless, pureconfig

I'm trying to use pureConfig and configFactory for my spark application configuration. 
here is my code:

```
import pureconfig.{loadConfigOrThrow}
object Source{
  def apply(keyName: String, configArguments: Config): Source = {
    keyName.toLowerCase match {
      case "mysql" =>
          val properties = loadConfigOrThrow[DBConnectionProperties](configArguments)
          new MysqlSource(None, properties)
      case "files" =>
        val properties = loadConfigOrThrow[FilesSourceProperties](configArguments)
        new Files(properties)
      case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException(s"Unknown Source ${keyName.toLowerCase}")
    }

  }
}

import Source
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(result.mkString("\n"))
    val source = Source("mysql",config.getConfig("source.mysql"))
```

when I run it from the IDE (intelliJ) or directly from java 
(i.e java jar...) it works fine.

But when I run it with spark-submit it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shapeless.Witness$.mkWitness(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lshapeless/Witness;
```

From a quick search I found a similar similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568010/nosuchmethoderror-in-shapeless-seen-only-in-spark). 
which suggest the reason for this is due to the fact both spark and pureConfig depends on Shapeless but with different versions,

I tried to [shade it](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) as suggested in the answer

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "shadeshapless.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.7.0").inProject
)
```

but it didn't work as well
can it be from a different reason?
any idea what may work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to shade shapeless inside its own JAR, in addition to pureconfig:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "shadeshapless.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2")
    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.7.0")
    .inProject
)
```

Make sure to add the correct shapeless version.

Comment: Coz of a [bug in sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/235) you have to add `scalaVersion` suffix to the library matching code mentioned in `inLibrary` like ` .inLibrary("com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2")`

Comment: @kaychaks I actually ran into that and managed to forget. Thanks for the tip, updated the answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think spark uses shapeless 2.0.0 via breeze (http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/shapeless-in-spark-2-1-0-td20392.htm)
when I ran your fix I got the following error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shapeless/DefaultSymbolicLabelling` 
should I shade spark shapeless dependency instead?

Comment: @LiorBaber No, you need to shade your own so your project picks up the correct version *you* need to work with.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I did, but it failed with the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shapeless/DefaultSymbolicLabelling`
here is what I did:

`libraryDependencies += "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2"

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "shadeshapless.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2")
    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.7.0")
    .inProject
)`

Comment: Did you open the JAR? Was the library properly shaded?

Comment: how can I know that?
should I extract the jar and look in the pureconfig classes?

Comment: Moreover, the issue  happened only when I use spark-submit meaning the spark dependencies are not included in the assembly jar (in Porvided scope)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142701/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-lior-baber).

Comment: Is there an answer to this question? I am facing the same problem for `0.8.0` https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig/issues/337 and cant get it to work in any of the suggested solutions.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You said in the issue that YARN client mode works fine. Did you properly distribute the shaded jars?

Comment: They are already included in the jar with the code for the job.

Comment: Also getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shapeless/DefaultSymbolicLabelling` when using the shading recommendation for maven.