# shapeless shading in spark not working - method still not found

Tags: apache-spark, classpath, shapeless, sbt-assembly, shading

Currently I face some problems with shapeless in spark 2.1 where still an outdated version of shapeless is being used. One of my dependencies(PureConfig current version of 0.8.0) pulls in a newer version of shapeless.

One should be able to use:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "new_shapeless.@1").inAll
)
```

to fix the `method not found` problem - but that does not help.

Also

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "shadeshapless.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2")
    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.8.0")
    .inProject
)
```

from [Spark not working with pureconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611147/spark-not-working-with-pureconfig) is suggested (and in my opinion should not be better than the `inAll` option) but  also fails (with a different error as this is now breaking the library (pureconfig).

Any suggestions to fix the shapeless problem?

## edit

currently, shading configuration looks like:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "shadeshapless.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2")
    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" % "pureconfig_2.11" % pureconfigVersion)
    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" % "pureconfig-macros_2.11" % pureconfigVersion)
    .inProject
)
```

Comment: ‘InAll’ means you’ll be scanning your entire dependency graph which can be time consuming as the graph gets large. You must likely don’t want that.

Comment: What happens when you try specifing the Scala version. i.e.  .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" % "pureconfig_2.11" % "0.8.0")

Comment: That indeed has some effect - but for now only leads to a lot of merge errors: `[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/com.github.pureconfig/pureconfig_2.11/bundles/pureconfig_2.11-0.8.0.jar:pureconfig/Derivation$.class
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/com.github.pureconfig/pureconfig-macros_2.11/jars/pureconfig-macros_2.11-0.8.0.jar:pureconfig/Derivation$.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:` but this should not have any different effect than `inAll`

Comment: Adding `    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" % "pureconfig-macros_2.11" % pureconfigVersion)
` will fix it locally. Only on Monday I will be able to confirm whether it works in yarn cluster mode - assuming the current shade settings produce the same output as `inAll` it probably won't work.  I will also try to experiment with `userclasspathFirst=true`.

Comment: Don't go with userClassPathFirst, that only leads to trouble.

Comment: So you meant best would be to switch to a non shapeless based library for now?

Comment: No, we just need to figure this out :)

Comment: But what else to shade ;) in case you have a YARN cluster at hand - maybe you can try: https://github.com/geoHeil/sparkMiniKickstart

Comment: Problem is im not near a computer now. Update on Monday if this works. If not, will try to dive into it deeper.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile, I set up a small projec to reproduce my problem: git clone git@github.com:geoHeil/sparkMiniKickstart.git cd sparkMiniKickstart  sbt compile

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but from spark 2.2 onwards it works fine as sparks dependency was upgraded.